# ¿Cómo hacer un deploy con git en hostinger?

Tags: git

Pongo el link HTTPS de mi repositorio en Github en hostinger como me lo piden, se queda cargando y al final me escribe "falla". ¿Que debo de hacer?

Saludos

Answer (score 2):

ya quedo, era problema del servidor de Hostinger, no era yo.

Pero fijense que usen el link https, he visto que a muchos no les funciona por eso.